# Python 3 Iterate file contents and pass each line into Popen statement

Tags: python, bash, python-3.5

I'm new to Python and am currently converting a bash script I've created into Python, due to reaching a point where bash was simply not the correct tool for the job.


I'm trying to read a file, iterate through each line in the file and then pass each line as a variable to the `Popen` command.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
lr = open(customoverridefile)
for line in lr.readlines():
    # print(line, end='')
    proc = Popen('autopkg repo-update {}'.format(line), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
    (out, err) = proc.communicate()
    print(out)
```

The result of this code is:

```
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I can't figure out how to pass the `line` variable to the `autopkg repo-update <line>` command in `Popen`. I left the commented out `print (line, end='')` in there because I am able to iterate through the file and simply print its contents.


Edit (for clarity): So my question is - how do I pipe in the variable `line` throughout the loop so that the command runs and the output is shown in terminal?


**UPDATE:**

I figured it out, thanks to help from the comments here. Each line was being appended with a UNIX line return `\n` - I resolved this by adding `universal_newlines=True` into my `Popen` command:

```
lr = open(overridesfile)
for line in lr.readlines():
    proc = Popen('autopkg make-override {}'.format(line), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
    (out, err) = proc.communicate()
    print(out, err, end='')
```

Thanks for the tips & help - glad this wasn't nearly as complicated as I was beginning to expect!


**FINAL UPDATE:**

I found a solution that formatted the items exactly as I needed. When using the code above, the items would output (and weren't being processed correctly) as such:

`['list item 1', 'list item 2', 'list item 3', ...]`

I discovered that I couldn't use this, however I found my solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list-with-python) StackOverflow post.

```
with open(overridesfile, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        overrideslist = line
        print(overrideslist, end='')
```

Again, hope this helps somebody in the future. Cheers!

Comment: is there a reason you're running this with `shell=True`? `proc = Popen(['autopkg', 'repo-update', line], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)` should work fine (I think)

Comment: if you want the output to go to the terminal you don't need to redirect stdout/stderr to a pipe. Otherwise you should probably also print `err`.

Comment: I can't remember now, but `file.readlines` might give you newline-terminated strings. try doing `line.strip()` instead.

Comment: @AdamSmith You are correct about both of your points - `shell=True` isn't necessary but I read somewhere that it's good to include it? I'll look into its use-case later tonight. In regards to `line.strip()`, this didn't work, however you are correct about there being a UNIX line return (`\n`) at the end of each line that was read. Found this when I modified my print statement to also print `err` - thanks @mata !